Is the group $\langle x,y:x^5=y^2=1\rangle$ a quotient of some subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb F)$?
The projective special linear group $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ is defined as $SL_2(\mathbb Z)/\langle -I\rangle$, where $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ is the special linear group. It is well known that $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ has the following presentation
$$
\langle x,y:x^3=y^2=1\rangle
$$
Is the following group, given by the presentation
$$
\langle x,y:x^5=y^2=1\rangle
$$
isomorphic to a quotient of some subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb F)$?

You may even want $\Bbb Z$ instead of $\Bbb F$?

$SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ contains a free group of countable rank so any countable group is a quotient of a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Thanks.  But how can I find this quotient group?

@boaz an explicit free subgroup of rank 2 is given here for example:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43726/the-free-group-f-2-has-index-12-in-sl2-mathbbz
Then just realize your desired 2-generated group as a quotient.
